# Twitter iPhone- is it possible to post on twitter using iphone app without providing pin number

Tags: iphone, twitter

i am using oAuth method for login to twitter in iPhone application... it need two steps to allow me to post. first is username and password authentication after validating it, twitter provides pin number to authorize... then i copy or memorize and send to twitter for authorize me to post for each and every time i login to twitter.

is it possible to post to twitter without entering pin number or copy the pin number provided by twitter and send the token internally without copy or mermorizing...

Thanks and regards
venkat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [xauth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth)

You need to get approval to use xauth:

> xAuth access is restricted to approved
>   applications. If your application is a
>   desktop or mobile application and the
>   standard web OAuth flow or PIN-code
>   out-of-band flow is not right for you,
>   send a detailed message to
>   api@twitter.com to request xAuth
>   privileges.

Comment: Thanks...if i use xauth in iphone app development its accepted by apple or not?

Comment: It is accepted and welcomed in Apple. Twitter recommends developer to use xauth in mobile environment.